# C: give 2D array to function but the identifier "a" is not defined

Tags: arrays, c, function, matrix

I want to create 2 matrices and fill them with reandom numbers 0-9.
I just don't understand why my function doesn`t work like this.
If I define a and b with e.g. #define a = 3 it works.
So the problem occurs at:

> void fillM(int array[a][b])

and

> void printM(int array[a][b])

#### Original code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


//fill random
void fillM(int array[a][b]) {
  for (int x=0; x < a; x++) {
    for (int y=0; y < b; y++) {
      array[x][y] = rand()%10;
    }
  }
}

//print 
void printM(int array[a][b]){
  for (int x=0; x < a; x++){
    for (int y=0; y < b; y++) {
      printf("%d ", array[a][b]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int Main(){

  //do I really need this?
  srand (time(NULL));

  //set size
  int n;
  printf("please set size of n x n Matrix: \n");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  int m = n;
  
  //initialise 
  int m1[n][m];
  int m2[n][m];

  fillM (m1);
  fillM (m2);

  return 0;
}
```

#### Revised code

```c
#include <float.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//fill random
void fillM(size_t a, size_t b, int array[a][b]) {
  for (int x=0; x < a; x++) {
    for (int y=0; y < b; y++) {
      array[x][y] = rand()%10;
    }
  }
}

//print 
void printM(size_t a, size_t b, int array[a][b]){
  for (int x=0; x < a; x++){
    for (int y=0; y < b; y++) {
      printf("%d ", array[a][b]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main(){

  srand (time(NULL));

  //set size
  int n;
  printf("please set size of n x n Matrix: \n");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("\n");
  int m = n;
  
  //initialise 
  int m1[n][m];
  int m2[n][m];

  fillM (n, m, m1);
  fillM (n, m, m2);

  printM (n, m, m1);
  printM (n, m, m2);

  return 0;
}
```

But one more question. If I run the program now, it doesn´t fill the matrix with random numbers everywhere. It puts the same random number in every place. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Aside: "Do I really need this? `srand (time(NULL));`?" While developing it's better to comment it out so that you get a repeatable sequence. Finally, randomize the PRNG to obtain a different sequence on each run.

Comment: thanks. But one more question. If I run the program now it doesn´t fill the matrix with random numbers everywhere. It puts the same random number in everyplace. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: You should not rewrite the question after you get an answer.

Comment: You are printing the same out of bounds element on each iteration.  Use `array[x][y]`.

Comment: I see, sorry. And thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

At the point where you use `a` and `b`, they are not defined.  You need something more like:

```
void fill(size_t a, size_t b, int array[a][b]
```

Your calls will pass the array size as well.

---

In your revised code, you get the same answer for every printed value because you attempt to print the same element of the array, `array[a][b]` — except that it isn't an element of the array but is a long way out of bounds because the array indexes run from `0..a-1` and `0..b-1`.  Use `array[x][y]` instead.